# Inserting multiple tables data using ADO.NET with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have created multiple tables in my database. They each other one-to-many relationships. And I wrote the stored procedure, but I can use it properly in C# code. Now I want to use it my service class method.

Code:

```
public void AddItem(Tshirt tshirt)
{
    if (tshirt == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    sqlConnection.Open();

    var cmdParameter = new List<SqlCommandParameter>();
    cmdParameter.Add(SqlCommandParameter.AddParameters("@Name", tshirt.Name));
    cmdParameter.Add(SqlCommandParameter.AddParameters("@ColorName", tshirt.Colors[1].ColorName));
    cmdParameter.Add(SqlCommandParameter.AddParameters("@ColorCode", tshirt.Colors[2].ColorCode));
    cmdParameter.Add(SqlCommandParameter.AddParameters("@TshirtId", tshirt.Colors[3].TshirtId));
    cmdParameter.Add(SqlCommandParameter.AddParameters("@SizeName", tshirt.Sizes[1].SizeName));
    cmdParameter.Add(SqlCommandParameter.AddParameters("@Height", tshirt.Sizes[2].Height));
    cmdParameter.Add(SqlCommandParameter.AddParameters("@Width", tshirt.Sizes[3].Width));
    cmdParameter.Add(SqlCommandParameter.AddParameters("@TshirtId", tshirt.Sizes[4].TshirtId));

    foreach(var item in cmdParameter)
    {
        if(item.ParameterValue == DBNull.Value)
        {
            cmdParameter.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    var execute = ExecuteScalarStoredProcedure("InsertItem", cmdParameter, sqlConnection);

    tshirt.Id = Convert.ToInt32(execute);
}
```

When I can't access my other class `Color` and `Size`, then I try to access the index number, but now I get an error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'

I couldn't understand which process need to go...

Comment: Why are you removing null valued parameters? That makes no sense. And I would be very surprised if any are `DBNull` since you mostly assigning strings to them they may be `null` but unlikely to be `DBNull`.

Comment: What line did it occur on? What was the index? What was the valid range? Did you not look or did you look and not tell us?

Comment: The only place where you use indexes is are the `Colors` and `Sizes` collections. Why do you assume this has anything to do with ADO.NET? Are you sure there are **4** colors and **5** sizes ? Do you really want to discard the first color and size of each t-shirt?

Comment: The first item is item `[0]`, not item `[1]`. And the code just looks *weird*. The `ColorName` and  `ColorCode` come from *different* `Color`s? And the `Color` has a `TshirtId`? Really? Similar questions about `Sizes`. You want the width from one `Size`, but the height from a different `Size`? That just seems unlikely.

Comment: I agree, the object model is very strange. Side note: you need `using` on `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`

Comment: @DaleK Even more nonsensical because `SqlCommand` doesn't pass `null` parameters at all, only if it's `DBNull.Value` then it gets passed

Comment: @john cmdParameter.Add(SqlCommandParameter.AddParameters("@ColorName", tshirt.Colors[1].ColorName)); this line

Comment: @Charlieface Ok

Comment: So how many items does `tshirt.Colors` have? You should have already debugged your code and know this. If 1 is an invalid index then presumably it has no more than one item, so you need to determine whether you have specific the incorrect index or failed to add the required items.

Comment: @John Ok, I'm check..

Comment: Thank you all, my problem is solved....

Comment: @allmhuran special thank deserve you. Thank you

Comment: You also need to wrap your connection objects in a USING statement. As posted your connections are not being properly handled and the connection pool is going to run out of connections.

Comment: It's my first project using stored procedure. Next time use using keyword..

Comment: Try this Nuget library : nuget.org/packages/Ado.Entity